# Unforgettable Factory: Doesn't work with default constructible objects

Tags: c++, factory

I am referring to this excellent blog post regarding the "Unforgettable Factory Registration Pattern": http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/

I've noticed that this stops working when the self-registering types are default constructible. In the example provided by the code, the self-registering types (`Animal` base class) defines  a constructor with an `int` parameter. If I slightly modify the code to make `Animal` become default constructible, the data map in the factory remains empty and objects of type `Cat` and `Dog` can no longer be constructed through the factory.

As far as I understand the issue lies in the fact that the `Animal` class no longer calls the `registerT` function. However, I fail to understand why that is and what modification(s) are necessary to make it work with default constructible classes.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Useful:

- Modified example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55fe8edc094c88a8
- Original example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11473a649e402831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` argument is a red herring. When changing the argument list you modified

```
Dog(int x) : m_x(x) {}
```

to be

```
Dog() = default;
```

From a user-provided constructor, to a defaulted one.

In effect, this means the compiler (I checked Clang and GCC) doesn't emit a function definition for `Dog::Dog()`, so it doesn't odr-use `Animal::Registrar<Dog>::Registrar<Dog>()`, which means its definition isn't instantiated (member function bodies only are only instantiated when odr-used). And so we never odr-use its `registered` static data member.

If the constructor is defaulted, then we never actually end up registering the factory function into the map. And indeed, after it becomes user-provided again, things [start to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8872c1edb200b5b).

I am however unable to understand why that makes a difference. The user-provided constructor is still an inline member function. And inline function definitions are tied to odr-usage too. But perhaps that should be the subject of another question.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  From what I can tell the default and empty constructor should be equivalent.  I'm designing a framework that will use a slightly modified version of this class and I'm concerned that users will use "= default" for their constructors.  Have you thought of a workaround to this?

Comment: @Stephan - I don't believe one exists. It bugged me enough to ask https://stackoverflow.com/q/65861630/817643 - Unless the standard changes, it's gonna be a risk that's only mitigated by documentation and **bold** font.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I think it's good that we have this as a reference for others that will no doubt stumble upon this.  Even though this behavior is expected as defined by the standard I find it extremely non-intuitive.  Having to resort to bold font in the docs is not the solution I was hoping for.  A hacky solution would be to add a dummy parameter to the Registrar constructor (i.e. Registrar(int)).  This will result in a "defaulted-function-warning" (or error if you use -Werror).  Still not ideal but better than nothing I guess.