# Why does an inline user-provided constructor odr-uses base class constructors?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Consider the following illustrative example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct Base {
    static int const touch;
    Base() {
        (void)touch;
    }
};

template<typename CRTP>
int const Base<CRTP>::touch = []{
    std::cout << "Initialized!\n";
    return 0;
}();

struct A : Base<A> {
    A() {} 
};

struct B : Base<B> {
    B() = default;
};

int main() {
}
```

When the above program is compiled by [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7l6RScgFkvbPeCZY), [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n0c7Nj7N2sRMPTq6) or [VC++](https://rextester.com/VIFKJ50959) and executed, one consistently sees the following output:

```
Initialized!
```

All three compilers emit the definition and initialization of `Base<A>::touch`, whereas neither emits the definition and initialization of `Base<B>::touch` (verified also via godbolt). So I would conclude this is standard sanctioned behavior.

For the defaulted constructor of `B`, we have

> **[class.ctor]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#7) A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used to create an object of its class type ([intro.object]) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

From which one may conclude that since neither condition applies in our TU, `B::B()` is never implicitly defined. So it never odr-uses `Base<B>::Base()` and `Base<B>::touch`. I find this reasonable.

However, I cannot understand why `A::A()` ends up odr-using the members of its base class. We know that

> **[class.mfct]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct#1) A member function may be defined in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member function ...
>
> **[dcl.inline]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.inline#6) An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case ([basic.def.odr]).
>
> **[basic.def.odr]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6) ... A constructor for a class is odr-used as specified in [dcl.init].

We never initialize any objects of type `A`, so we shouldn't be odr-using its constructor. And so our program wouldn't end up containing any definition of `A::A()`.

So why does it behave as though a definition exists? Why does it odr-use `Base<A>::Base()` and causes its instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens for *any* inline definition that odr-uses `Base<T>::Base`, for example:

```cpp
inline void x() {
    Base<char>();
}

struct A : Base<A> {
    A(int) {}
    void x() {
        Base<int>();
    }
};

struct C : Base<C> {
    C();
};

inline C::C() = default;  // See [1]

// Will print "Initialized!" four times
```

`B() = default` does not odr-use `Base<T>::Base` because it is only defined as [defaulted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def-2). Even though structurally a definition according to [[basic.def]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def-2), it is not "emitted" because of [class.ctor]/7 (as you quoted). The definition that would odr-use `Base<T>::Base` will only be (implicitly) defined if and when `B::B()` is odr-used itself.

For other inline functions that are defined, there does not exist such an exemption. Their definitions unconditionally (and structurally) contain an odr-use `Base<T>::Base`. `A::A()` in your example is a definition, and your program *does* contain a definition of `A::A()` that uses `Base<T>::Base`.

*"An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used"*. This is a "shall" requirement (for every TU in which an inline function is odr-used, a definition is required), not the consequence of odr-using an inline function.

---

[1] As a consequence of [[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#default-5):

> A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly defaulted

So `C::C()` has a default definition which immediately generates the "implicit" definition.